# Android image in QEMU

Tags: android, qemu

How to launch `qemu` with android image tha i've built from `Android` sources?

Qemu returns that my image is not bootdable disk.

Steps:
1. I've download and built `qemu`
2. I've download and built `Android image`
3. Trying to start qemu with following command: 
`qemu-system-i386 system.img`

and I've got following error:

```
Booting from hard Disk
Boot failed: not ad bootable disk
```

Same error with `-hdd` option

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are using the wrong architecture. Try qemu-system-arm instead.